# How create and read javascript object for save the following data structure?

Tags: javascript

I need to create the following data structure:

```
userid, onlinetime, offlinetime
```

I need the user id to be repeated in the list.

Something like this:

```
userid: 1, onlinetime: 11:10:30, offlinetime: 11:18:12
userid: 1, onlinetime: 11:14:14, offlinetime: 11:52:41
userid: 2, onlinetime: 8:08:14, offlinetime: 1:15:00
```

How can I create this object, or a list?

How can I read this object or list? (I need to compare on-line and off-line time.)

Comment: How is represented the data at first ? You generate it from server-side, you get it from forms elements, or request json... ?

Comment: Create an object from a javascript function. The function returns the user id, online time, offline time.

Comment: From your example, it seems a single user can have multiple online and offline times. Also, it would make more sense to have a connectionTimes array, which will contain online and offline times. This can be a part of an object with a userID property.

Comment: @Abbas This is a good solution. Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create User objects with userId and connectionTimes properties and add them to an array of Users like this:

```
function createUsers()
{
    var users = [];

    users[0] = {
        userId: 1,
        connectionTimes:
            [
                {onlineTime:"11:10:30", offlineTime:"11:18:12"},
                {onlineTime:"11:14:14", offlineTime:"11:52:41"}
            ]
    }

    users[1] = {
        userId: 2,
        connectionTimes: 
            [
                {onlineTime:"8:08:14", offlineTime:"1:15:00"}
            ]
    }   

    return users;
}
```

Once you have an array of users, you can iterate through it and find a user by comparing the userId property:

```
var users = createUsers();

for (var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
{
    if (users[i].userId === 2)
    {
        for (var j=0;j<users[i].connectionTimes.length;j++)
        {
            alert("onlineTime: " + users[i].connectionTimes[j].onlineTime + ", " + "offlineTime: " + users[i].connectionTimes[j].offlineTime);
        }   
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a decomposed version of the code, based on a createUser and getConnectionTime function:

```
function getConnectionTime(onTime, offTime)
{
    return {onlineTime: onTime, offlineTime: offTime};
}

function createUser(uid, connTimes)
{
    return {userId: uid, connectionTimes: connTimes};
}

var users = [];

var connTimes = [];
connTimes.push(getConnectionTime("11:10:30", "11:18:12"));
connTimes.push(getConnectionTime("11:14:14", "11:52:41"));
users.push(createUser(1, connTimes));

connTimes = [];
connTimes.push(getConnectionTime("8:08:14", "1:15:00"));
users.push(createUser(2, connTimes));

for (var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
{
    if (users[i].userId === 2)
    {
        for (var j=0;j<users[i].connectionTimes.length;j++)
        {
            alert("onlineTime: " + users[i].connectionTimes[j].onlineTime + ", " + "offlineTime: " + users[i].connectionTimes[j].offlineTime);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: When I need to generate userid and times dynamically. How I can read the time from the user with id 2?

Comment: This is very good! Could you please show me: How to dynamically generate this object? : `users[0] = {
        userId: 1,
        connectionTimes: 
            [
                {onlineTime:"11:10:30", offlineTime:"11:18:12"},
                {onlineTime:"11:14:14", offlineTime:"11:52:41"}
            ]
    }`

Comment: That depends on how you generate the userId and connectionTimes. From where are you getting/generating these values?

Comment: Input of function createUser userid = 1 and the online and offline time. `function createUser(userid, onlinetime, offlinetime)
{
    //create array with for examples: userid = 1, onlinetime = 1:11:11, offlinetime = 7:07:15 
   //When the user record exist with id = 1, so only add time.
       
}`

Comment: The createUser function cannot have onlinetime and offlinetime parameters since a single user can have more then 1 pair of online and offline time. This is what I think the create user function should look like: function createUser(userid, connectionTimes) { ... }. I will update my answer and break down the object into functions.

Comment: Could you please make an example? How exactly do input?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. How can i update the user with id 1 - and add new time - When the user exist?

Comment: users[0].connectionTimes.push(getConnectionTime("00:00:00", "00:00:01"))

Comment: How do I know that a user with id 1 has a sequence number 0?

Comment: I was just giving an example. You will have to search it as I have demonstrated in the code above. The condition would be: if (users[i].userId === 1).